# nginx logging: Is there a way to log request time in milliseconds since Unix epoch?

Tags: nginx, logging, log-files

I'm aware of the [`$msec` logging parameter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) which gives the request time as seconds since Unix epoch with millisecond granularity. However, the format of this includes a period '.' e.g. '1407233265.472' and this is a problem for the import function that I'm using to parse the log files.

Is there a way (log parameter or plugin) that will allow the request time to be recorded in total milliseconds? e.g. '1407233265472'. Am happy to compile nginx as required.

Comment: Before using a nonstandard (as in not coming from the distro repos) web server, I would consider to send the logs through `sed` before importing them to your tool.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways to achieve this. The first one is dirty and I wont recommend it - it's the fastest way though:

```
if ($msec ~ "(.*)\.(.*)") {
    set $epoch_millis = "$1$2"
}
```

This is much cleaner but requires lua:

```
set_by_lua_block $epoch_millis { return string.gsub(ngx.var.msec, "%.", "") }
```

then just log $epoch_millis

Comment: What will happen when the value is 1407233265.4? The resulting value will be 14072332654. So it is a wrong answer.

Comment: nginx pads the decimal spot with zeroes, so won't emit anything more/less than 3 decimal places

Answer (score 2):

Extending Sirk's answer you can also use a map to convert from the 10.3 millisecond format to the 13 digit millisecond epoch format which has no decimal.

```
map $msec $msec_no_decimal { ~(.*)\.(.*) $1$2; }
```

Specifically I needed to put this map inside the `http { ... }` block of nginx.conf because DataDog doesn't automatically parse the 10.3 format, but does parse the 13 digit format.

(to address sanigo's concern; nginx pads zeroes on the decimal, so this will always convert to 13 digits.)